# PEAR: Preferred state not changing

Tags: pear

I'm new to PEAR framework of PHP. I just installed everything fine using steps from [this](http://phphints.wordpress.com/2008/08/26/installing-pear-package-manager-on-wamp/) tutorial page. But a while ago when I attempted to change installation state from `stable` to `beta` I'm getting the following error.

```
shell>pear config-set preferred_state beta
config-set (preferred_state, stable, user) failed, channel pear.php.net
```

I've done this before and it worked fine. But now it doesn't. As far as I know I haven't changed anything in `php.ini` files.

What could be the problem?

Comment: If you are on unix, you may want to check the ownership and permissions of your ~/.pearrc file. Make sure it it owned by your user with chown and the permissions are 644 (witch chmod).

Comment: also try `pear -vvvvv config-set ...`